# Quickdialog QEnteryElement with multiple lines?

Tags: ios, uitableview, quickdialog

My app uses Quickdialog to create a form for the user.
Now i have created an QEnteryElement with an title and placeholder.
But when an user types an text that is longer than one line the text with hide behind the title.

So how do i create an 'QEnteryElement' with multiple lines with a height that is lock to like say 200.

```
 `QEnteryElement.height = 200 //works for the height`
```

And scrolling in that field and return is enabled.

And yes i now of the QMulitilineElement, but this uses a new viewcontroller to enter the text and this is not in style with the app.

Answer (score 0):

QEntryElement creates cell with text field which can display only single line of text.
Try to create your own subclass of QLabelElement or QRootElement and its counterpart cell subclass with text view inside. And override this method, where you should configure your cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)getCellForTableView:(QuickDialogTableView *)tableView controller:(QuickDialogController *)controller
```

Comment: Going to give it a try.

Comment: I think i'm doing it wrong. Because it will not work. 
Any guidance would we appreciated. (IOS NOOB BTW)